# How does one compute mutual and self inductance for real coils?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, inductance

I have computer models where I am trying to compute the mutual inductance between two coils.  I have simplified the model in the following picture where I have two coils, 1 and 2, with different geometries and different numbers of turns: $N_1$ and $N_2$, respectively.

[image]

As I know the magnetic field everywhere, I should be able to compute the mutual inductance given by: $M_{12}=\frac{N_1 \Phi_1}{I_2}$ where $\Phi_1$ is the flux through coil 1 and $I_2$ is the current in coil 2.  The question is where do I calculate the flux?  Do I use a disk at the front, back, or middle of coil 1, and should that disk's radius be equal to the inner or outer radius of coil 1?  The flux is obviously going to be different depending on my choice of surface.

Bonus question: Say I had a coil that looked like the Baseball 2 coil used at Lawrence Livermore in the 1960's (pictured below---the coils looked like the seams on a baseball) and I wanted to calculate the flux through that.  What should my flux surface look like?

[image]

Comment: NIST have produced a number of documents about the calculation of self and mutual inductance which also include many references. Here is one https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/bulletin/05/nbsbulletinv5n1p1_A2b.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This is helpful for simple cases, but I realize that my problem is more complex for two reasons: my conductors aren't always simple shapes and there is iron present.    I will think about this further.